# How to clean up old connections from EDMX Wizard in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, edmx, ef-database-first, edmx-designer

When using EF Database-First wizard for EDMX creation, there is a dropdown containing connections that were created previously; these may linger around long after the database is no longer relevant. The connections cannot be edited or deleted from the wizard interface, only new ones created.

See screenshot, under "What data connection should your application use to connect to the database?"

Where does dropdown data get stored, because I so want to clean them up / blast them away / nuke them forever / start with a fresh slate?
[image: edmx wizard]

I am using Visual Studio 2015, but it's probably the same for other versions.

Comment: look in app.config of your project and remove old ones . Does this work? 

Comment: @magicandre if it was that easy in looking at app.config i would have known about it already. It's nothing to do with the current project. I can start a new project with a blank app.config.. and any previous connections remain in the wizard from 10 years ago.. (i am exagerating a bit).